# AngularJs Filter an array by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have three arrays in a controller:

1. `$scope.allUsers` containing all users by `:id` and `:name`. E.g. smth like [this](http://www.json-generator.com/j/bLucYdLdpe).
2. `$scope.job.delegated_to` containing information related to job delegation. Looks like this.

```
    $scope.job.delegated_to = [
      {id: 5, user_id:33, user_name:"Warren", hour_count:4},
      {id: 5, user_id:18, user_name:"Kelley", hour_count:2},
      {id: 5, user_id:10, user_name:"Olson", hour_count:40},
      {id: 5, user_id:42, user_name:"Elma", hour_count:2},
      {id: 5, user_id:45, user_name:"Haley", hour_count:4},
      {id: 5, user_id:11, user_name:"Kathie", hour_count:3}
     ]
```

3. `$scope.freeUsers` which has to contain all the users, not delegated to the job.

I added a watch

```
$scope.$watch('job.delegated_to.length', function(){
  $scope.freeUsers = filterUsers( $scope.allUsers, $scope.job.delegated_to );
});
```

but have not been able to construct a working filter.

Comment: While @dubadub answers the OP question correctly, I think the OP might have meant something else: using an angular ```$Filter``` that can be used on an ```ng-repeat``` directive. @Almaron can you clarify?

Comment: @alonisser, either way is fine. Whichever does the job.

Comment: just notice that this kind of filter can be used only in the controller. if you want to use it in template with ``` ng-repeat freeUsers | nonAssignedUsers``` you'll have to encapsulate one of the suggested filters within an angular [$Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filterUsers function would be like:

```
var filterUsers = function(allUsers, jobs) {
    var freeUsers = allUsers.slice(0); //clone allUsers
    var jobUserIds = [];
    for(var ind in jobs) jobUserIds.push(jobs[ind].user_id);
    var len = freeUsers.length;
    while(len--){
      if(jobUserIds.indexOf(allUsers[len].id) != -1)  freeUsers.splice(len, 1);
    }    
    return freeUsers;
}
```

Checkout fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cQXBv/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a library like [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/), which has many useful utility functions. You could then write your filter function as:

```
function filterUsers(allUsers, delegatedTo) {
    var delegatedIndex = _.indexBy(delegatedTo, 'user_id');
    return _.reject(allUsers, function(user) {return user.id in delegatedIndex});
}
```